# Fitting any Vector3 (x,y,z) into a linear array index

Tags: c#, math, vector

The purpose of the function below is that an array of random numbers is generated using a seed - rnd[], and the lookup below is a fast way to find a random number associated with a given coordinate. Seems like this function converts any coordinates (x,y,z) in 3D space into an index of a fixed length array of 8192. I'm not sure if the function is accurate or not, I assume it is, but I wanted to use a much larger array than below. I feel like it isn't random enough with only 8192 of random numbers to use.

How would I change the code to work with an array that is 262144 instead of 8192 in length?

```
public static float GetValue(Vector3 position) {
    long hash = 17 * 23 + (long)position.x;
    hash = hash * 23 + (long)position.y;
    hash = hash * 23 + (long)position.z;
    hash += (hash >> 26) + (hash >> 13);
    rndIndex = (uint)(hash & 8191);
    return (float)rnd[rndIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about

```
 rnd[position.GetHashCode() % rnd.Length];
```

this will take any vector, use GetHashCode to convert the vector to an int, and use the modulus operator to restrict the result to the length of the array. This assumes that GetHashCode is well defined.

If you want vectors close to each other to be mapped to the same number you could use something like:

```
var hashCode = (long)position.X;
hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^  (long)position.Y;
hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^  (long)position.Z;
```

instead of GetHashCode.

Another alternative would be to put random numbers in a 3D-array instead, and use the vector to index into that instead, using the modulus operator to ensure each coordinate is mapped to the valid range.

Comment: Cool thank you, I was wondering how to do that and it could be useful but I believe the code is intentionally staggering the results so that X,Y,Z values close together do not get the same index. A position of 5,5,5 should not get the same index as 5,5,4 and that code achieves it but I wanted to expand the array to get more random values to select from because I think the same values are coming up a little too often. The 26 bit shift always results in zero until you have really large numbers so I think it already accounts for a large range of X,Y,Z and I just wanted to increase the array size.

Comment: if you are happy with your hash method, just replace `hash & 8191` with `hash % rnd.Length` and use however long array you want.